# android SQLite no such table (code 1) error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm import a SQLite database in my android project(into assets folder). and i want to access it and show the records. but when i try it. get that error

[image: my db in assets folder]

[image: my database column and fields]

DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DB_PATH;
//Veritabanı ismini veriyoruz
static String DB_NAME = "ogrenci";

SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/databases/";

    this.myContext = context;
}
//Assest dizinine koyduğumuz sql dosyasını, Android projesi içine oluşturma ve kopyalamna işlemi yapıldı..
public void CreateDataBase()
{
    boolean dbExists = checkDataBase();

    if (!dbExists)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try
        {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.w("hata","Veritabanı kopyalanamıyor");
            throw new Error("Veritabanı kopyalanamıyor.");
        }
    }
}
//Sqlite veritabanı dosyasını açıp, veritabanımı kontrol ediyoruz
boolean checkDataBase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try
    {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.w("hata","Veritabanı açılamadı");
    }

    if (checkDB != null)
        checkDB.close();

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
///Assest dizinine koyduğumuz sql dosyasındaki verileri kopyalıyoruz
void copyDataBase()
{
    try
    {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();

        myInput.close();
        myOutput.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.w("hata", "Kopya oluşturma hatası.");
    }
}
//Veritabannı açma işlemi yapıldı

void openDataBase()
{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close()
{
    if (myDatabase != null && myDatabase.isOpen())
        myDatabase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Corba1 class

```
public class F_corba1 extends Fragment {

View parent;
Context con;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // text_baslik=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.text_baslik);

    parent=inflater.inflate(R.layout.corba1,container,false);
    con=inflater.getContext();

    //DatabaseHelper sınıfımızdaki CreateDataBase methodunu çağırıp , assest dizinine koymuş
    //olduğumuz veritabanını,Android projesinin içinde  oluşturup,verileri kopyalamasını sağladık...
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(con);
    try
    {
        dbHelper.CreateDataBase();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.w("hata","Veritabanı oluşturulamadı ve kopyalanamadı!");
    }


    //Proje içine kopyalanmış olan veritabanımızdan verileri listview e yazdırdık

    SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] getColumnName={"student_name,student_surname"};
    Cursor imlec=db.query("student", getColumnName, null, null, null, null, null);
    ListView listview=(ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList<String> student=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(con,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,student);

    while(imlec.moveToNext()){
        String student_name=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("student_name"));
        String student_surname=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("student_surname"));
        String name_surname= student_name+ " "+student_surname;
        student.add(name_surname);

    }
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    imlec.close();
    db.close();

    return parent;
}


}
```

error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.yeni, PID: 26479
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT student_name,student_surname FROM student
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
        at com.yeni.corbalar.F_corba1.onCreateView(F_corba1.java:63)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line into error (F_corba1.java:63)

```
 Cursor imlec=db.query("student", getColumnName, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: check your ogrenci.sql  whether it has a table with the name student

Comment: @serdar öztüfekçi Try my answer

Comment: I can't see where you have created your table. As I can see, You have only created a database. First you create a table and then access this.

Comment: @Mansuu.... i think thats wrong. have you any different idea ?

Comment: You can do one thing, when you are going to access table write a method to check whether table exists or not, if not then create a new one otherwise do whatever you want with the table.

Answer (score 2):

I think your path to your database is wrong. In your case you can get a path to your database in assets folder like this:

```
DB_PATH = "file:///android_asset/School.db"
```

Or you can get your database as an InputStream:

```
InputStream dbInputStream = context.getAssets().open("School.db");
```

Comment: yes you're right. i'm fix the "DB_PATH" but still i get same error. please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DB_PATH;
//Veritabanı ismini veriyoruz
static String DB_NAME = "School.db";
```

Comment: i try this. but i still get same error. have you different idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below one.

```
 public class F_corba1 extends Fragment {

View parent;
Context con;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // text_baslik=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.text_baslik);

parent=inflater.inflate(R.layout.corba1,container,false);
con=inflater.getContext();

//DatabaseHelper sınıfımızdaki CreateDataBase methodunu çağırıp , assest dizinine koymuş
//olduğumuz veritabanını,Android projesinin içinde  oluşturup,verileri kopyalamasını sağladık...
DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(con);
try
{
    dbHelper.CreateDataBase();
    dbHelper.copyDataBase();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.w("hata","Veritabanı oluşturulamadı ve kopyalanamadı!");
}


//Proje içine kopyalanmış olan veritabanımızdan verileri listview e yazdırdık

SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] getColumnName={"student_name,student_surname"};
Cursor imlec=db.query("student", getColumnName, null, null, null, null, null);
ListView listview=(ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayList<String> student=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(con,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,student);

while(imlec.moveToNext()){
    String student_name=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("student_name"));
    String student_surname=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("student_surname"));
    String name_surname= student_name+ " "+student_surname;
    student.add(name_surname);

}
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
imlec.close();
db.close();

return parent;
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call         dbHelper.copyDataBase(); method

Comment: i add "dbHelper.copyDataBase();" and try but still i get same error. please help.

Comment: InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(ogrenci.sqlite);
Pass full name of sqlite db from assets.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use db in assets folder.
assets folder just for read you cant save or update any file in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You did not `copied` you database `School.db` to `ogrenci`. Just call `copyDataBase()` method from your `DatabaseHelper` `onCreate()` method.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    copyDataBase();
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: i add "copyDataBase();" and try but still i get same error. please help.